# Continously read file in Ruby and save into pipe

Tags: ruby, file, io, ffmpeg

I am trying to continously read a file and save the output into a `IO.pipe`. The motivation being that ffmpeg which has been spawned before and given the r-end of the pipe as STDIN will then convert the video.
This is what I have so far:

```
    r,w = IO.pipe
    ffmpeg_args = ' -i pipe:0 "test.mp4"'
    pid = Process.spawn('ffmpeg'+ffmpeg_args, {STDIN => r, STDERR => STDOUT})
    Process.detach pid
    File.open(@options['filename'], 'rb') do |file|
      while line = file.gets
        w.write line.read
      end
    end
```

I had success with declaring the input file directly as STDIN for the process, but this lead to an early termination of ffmpeg since it had reached the end of the file. With the code above ffmpeg complains about invalid data.

Is there any way this could be achieved?